# Passing expression through functions

Tags: r, expression, data.table

I'm using `data.table` package and trying to write a function (shown below):

```
require(data.table)
# Function definition
f = function(path, key) {
  table = data.table(read.delim(path, header=TRUE))
  e = substitute(key)
  setkey(table, e) # <- Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose) : some columns are not in the data.table: e
  return(table)
}

# Usage
f("table.csv", ID)
```

Here I try to pass an expression to the function. Why this code doesn't work?

I've already tried different combinations of `substitute()`, `quote()` and `eval()`. So, it'd be great if you could also explain how to get this to work.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? 

Also your code currently won't even get to that step; `data.table` is not a function.

Comment: Why not to simply use `setkeyv` here and give the ID as a character?

Comment: @Manetheran, probably the OP should've mentioned that he's using the `data.table` package. Just made the edit and added the tag.

Comment: Ah, I am not familiar with that package, that'd be why the question made no sense to me!

Comment: @Arun Thanks I've forgotten to mention that.

Comment: @agstudy the aim is not to just do the trick but to understand how this kind of things works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### First, let's look at how the `setkey` function does things from the `data.table` package:

```
# setkey function
function (x, ..., verbose = getOption("datatable.verbose")) 
{
    if (is.character(x)) 
        stop("x may no longer be the character name of the data.table. The possibility was undocumented and has been removed.")
    cols = getdots()
    if (!length(cols)) 
        cols = colnames(x)
    else if (identical(cols, "NULL")) 
        cols = NULL
    setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose)
}
```

So, when you do:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3), y = 1:5)
setkey(dt, ID)
```

It calls the function `getdots` which is internal to `data.table` (that is, it's not exported). Let's have a look at that function:

```
# data.table:::getdots
function () 
{
    as.character(match.call(sys.function(-1), call = sys.call(-1), 
        expand.dots = FALSE)$...)
}
```

So, what does this do? It takes the parameter you entered in `setkey` and it uses `match.call` to extract the arguments separately. That is, the `match.call` argument for this example case would be:

```
setkey(x = dt, ... = list(ID))
```

and since it's a list, you can access the `...` parameter with `$...` to get a list of 1 element with its value `ID` and converting to this list to a character with `as.character` results in `"ID"` (a character vector). And then `setkey` passes this to `setkeyv` internally to set the keys.

---

#### Now why doesn't this work when you write `setkey(table, key)` inside your function?

This is precisely because of the way `setkey/getdots` is. The `setkey` function is designed to take any argument after the first argument (which is a `data.table`) and then return the `...` argument as a character.

That is, if you give `setkey(dt, key)` then it'll return `cols <- "key"`. If you give `setkey(dt, e)`, it'll give back `cols <- "e"`. It doesn't look for if "key" is an existing variable and then if so substitute the value of the variable. All it does is convert the value you provide (whether it be a symbol or character) back to a character.

Of course this won't work in your case because you want the value in `key` = ID to be provided in `setkey`. At least I can't think of a way to do this.

---

#### How to get around this?

As @agstudy already mentions, the best/easiest way is to pass `"ID"` and use `setkeyv`. But, if you really insist on using `f("table.csv", ID)` then, this is what you could do:

```
f <- function(path, key) {
    table = data.table(read.delim(path, header=TRUE))
    e = as.character(match.call(f)$key)
    setkeyv(table, e)
    return(table)
}
```

Here, you first use `match.call` to get the value corresponding to argument `key` and then convert it to a `character` and then pass that to `setkeyv`.

In short, `setkey` internally uses `setkeyv`. And imho, setkey is a convenient function to be used when you already know the column name of the `data.table` for which you need to set the key. Hope this helps.

Comment: Arun can I claim that `setkey` is actually a handy function/ shortcut to `setkeyv`? I mean it is intended to be used at the console level for example? +1

Comment: @agstudy, precisely. That's what the last paragraph from the post says as well :).

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear. I've watched through `setkey()` implementation but I should go deeper and take a look at `getdots()` as well.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell from your code what you're trying to achieve, so I'll answer the question the title asks instead; "How to pass an expression through a function?"

If you want to do this (this should be avoided where possible), you can do the following:

```
f <- function(expression) {
  return(eval(parse(text=expression)))
}
```

For example:

```
f("a <- c(1,2,3); sum(a)")
# [1] 6
```