# Use data.table in functions/packages (With roxygen)

Tags: r, windows, data.table, testthat

I am quite new to R but it seems, this question is closely related to the following post [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527072/using-data-table-package-inside-my-own-package), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039194/making-a-package-in-r-that-depends-on-data-table), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547235/r-data-table-and-testthat-package) and a bit different topic [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036775/passing-expression-through-functions). Unfortunately, I have not enough reputation to comment right there. My problem is that after going through all the suggestions there, the code still does not work:

1. I included "Depends" in the description file
2. <strike>I tried the second method including a change of NAMESPACE</strike>  (Not reproducable)
3. I created a **example package** [here](https://github.com/Christoph999/UseDT) containing a very small part of the code which showed a bit different error (`"J" not found in routes[J(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2), .I, roll = "nearest", by = .EACHI]` instead of `'lat1' not found in routes[order(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, time)]`)
4. I tested all scripts using the console and R-scripts. There, the code ran without problems.

Thank you very much for your support!

**Edit**: @Roland

1. You are right. Roxygen overwrites the namespace. You have to include `#' @import data.table` to the function. Do you understand, why only inserting `Depends: data.table` in the DESCRIPTION file does not work? This might be a useful hint in the documentation or did I miss it?
2. It was missleading that changing to routes <- routes[order("lat1", "lng1", "lat2", "lng2", "time")] helped at least a bit as this line was suddenly no problem any more. Is it correct, that in this case data.frame order is used? I will see how far I get now. I will let you know the final result...

Comment: 1) Add data.table to Imports (not Depends), 2) add `import(data.table)` to the NAMESPACE file. That's it. Are you possibly using roxygen2, which might rewrite your NAMESPACE file?

Comment: If you haven't read already: [R-exts manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your questions (after edit).

1. Quoting R exts manual:

> Almost always packages mentioned in ‘Depends’ should also be imported from in the NAMESPACE file: this ensures that any needed parts of those packages are available when some other package imports the current package.

So you still should have import in NAMESPACE despite the fact if you depends or import data.table.

2. The `order` call doesn't seems to be what you expect, try the following:

```
order("lat1", "lng1", "lat2", "lng2", "time")

library(data.table)
data.table(a=2:1,b=1:2)[order("a","b")]
```

In case of issues I recommend to start debugging by writing unit test for your expected results. The most basic way to put unit tests in package is just plain R script in `tests` directory having `stopifnot(...)` call. Be aware you need to library/require your package at the start of the script.

Comment: Ok. That means answer 1. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527072/using-data-table-package-inside-my-own-package) is not correct? The issue with `order` is working fine now. I just wanted to know whether the reason was (I didn't change the NAMESPACE!) that it was a data.frame `order` function. Am I correct?

Comment: @Christoph If you use it in data.table, then AFAIK it was not a base order, unless you turn off optimization in data.table option or call `base::order` directly

Comment: Be aware that it will change soon in R 3.3.0 as base R gets data.table order function merged. See [NEWS file for R 3.3.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html) for more details.

Comment: Ok. What about the first answer in the reference above? I think this is wrong then?

Comment: It may not reflect the current R release requirement. I did update it a moment ago, will followup with update in data.table FAQ about it.

Comment: I would suggest, I throw out part 2. in my Edit as it will be confusing for others? It would be great if you could help me with my last (a bit off-topic) issue here: As you can see, my routes contain `lat1, lng1, ...` If I now make a function `find_routes <- function(routes, lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2){found_route <- routes[.(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2), nomatch = 0L]}` it will take the columns `lat1, lng1, ...` from the routes file and NOT the arguments given in the function. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110281/discussion-between-christoph-and-jangorecki).

Answer (score 0):

This is more in addition to the answers above: I found this to be really useful...

From the docs [Hadley-description](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html und)

> Imports   packages listed here must be present for your package to
>   work. In fact, any time  your package is installed, those packages
>   will, if not already present, be installed on  your computer
>   (`devtools::load_all()` also checks that the packages are installed).
>
> Adding a package dependency here ensures that it’ll be installed.
>   However, it does not  mean that it will be attached along with your
>   package (i.e., library(x)). The best  practice is to explicitly refer
>   to external functions using the syntax `package::function()`.  This
>   makes it very easy to identify which functions live outside of your
>   package. This  is especially useful when you read your code in the
>   future.
>
> If you use a lot of functions from other packages this is rather
>   verbose. There’s also  a minor performance penalty associated with
>   `::` (on the order of 5$\mu$s, so it will only  matter if you call the
>   function millions of times).

From the docs [Hadley-namespace](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#imports)

> NAMESPACE also controls which external functions can be used by your
>   package without having to use `::`. It’s confusing that both
>   DESCRIPTION (through the Imports field) and NAMESPACE (through import 
>   directives) seem to be involved in imports. This is just an
>   unfortunate choice of names. The  Imports field really has nothing to
>   do with functions imported into the namespace: it just makes  sure the
>   package is installed when your package is. It doesn’t make functions
>   available. You  need to import functions in exactly the same way
>   regardless of whether or not the package is attached.
>   ...  **this is what I recommend**: list the package in DESCRIPTION so that it’s
>   installed, then  always refer to it explicitly with `pkg::fun()`.
>   Unless there is a strong reason not to, it’s  better to be explicit.
>   It’s a little more work to write, but a lot easier to read when you 
>   come back to the code in the future. The converse is not true. Every
>   package mentioned in  NAMESPACE must also be present in the Imports or
>   Depends fields.